# Problem with images and text

Tags: graphics, text

I find myself doing a document in latex that has many images, when I insert the images two problems arise, the first is that it leaves me too large spaces in white, the second is that the text between images is very messy.
I was wondering if there is any way to "tie" the text to the images so that they come together and the document is more organized, I know that the blank spaces arise due to the size of the images.
I enclose a fraction of the code and image.

Una vez finalizado el terreno, se realiza el alineaminto horizontal bajo los siguientes criterios:\
En primer lugar, se dibujan las tangentes, esto se hace de la siguiente manera:\
Se dibuja una línea para cada tangente (comando: L LINEA/LINE):\

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Terrenocontangentes.pdf}
\caption{Terreno con las tangentes}
\label{fig:ejemplo}
\end{figure}
```

Una vez dibujadas las tangentes, se crea la alineación a partir de las líneas.

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apartirdeobj.jpg}
\caption{Alineación a partir de objetos}
\label{fig:ejemplo}
\end{figure}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: the reason that figures float is to avoid getting large white space at page breaks, by using `[H]` you are opting to disable floating so will get large spaces unless you carefully position the images by hand to fit with your text and page breaks.

Comment: forgetting the problem with the blank spaces, it is possible to do something so that a portion of the text is always next to the image that I insert? something like concatenating or joining text and figure

Comment: You can put text inside a figure (you may have to change \parindent etc.) .

Comment: Concatenating: Perhaps package `wrapfig` will help you?